# Change mixin variable based on media (or some other condition)

Tags: less

Say I have a complex mixin function. Something like

```
.MyMixin(@Count, @ManyOtherVars)
{
  .Item 
  { 
    width: calc( 100% / @Count);
  }
  //lot's of other rules not affected by @Count
}
```

And then I want to call this mixin with different values for different media
e.g.

```
.SomeClass
{
  @media screen (max-width: 1000px)
  {
    .MyMixin(5, 1);
  }
  @media screen (min-width: 1000px)
  {
    .MyMixin(10, 1);
  }
}
```

This works fine, except the generated css duplicates all the stuff which has not changed

```
@media screen (max-width: 1000px)
{
  .SomeClass .Item
  {
    width: calc( 100% / 5 );
  }
  .SomeClass 
  {
    /* lot's of other rules not affected by @Count */
  }
}

@media screen (min-width: 1000px)
{
  .SomeClass .Item
  {
    width: calc( 100% / 10 );
  }
  .SomeClass 
  {
    /* lot's of other rules not affected by @Count */
  }
}
```

Which, needless to say, is quite wasteful when only one thing changed.

Are there any workarounds to produce a leaner output that don't require the calling class to know something about what the mixin does, or for the mixin to know about media rules?
I thought maybe a detached rule-set could help, but given variables are not exported from those I'm not sure how it would.

Desired output:

```
@media screen (max-width: 1000px)
{
  .SomeClass .Item
  {
    width: calc( 100% / 5 );
  }
}

@media screen (min-width: 1000px)
{
  .SomeClass .Item
  {
    width: calc( 100% / 10 );
  }
}
.SomeClass 
{
  /* lot's of other rules not affected by @Count */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove static styles from your mixin and place them directly to `SomeClass` selector.

```
.SomeClass {
  // Lot's of other rules not affected by @Count

  @media screen (max-width: 1000px) {
    .MyMixin(5, 1);
  }
  @media screen (min-width: 1000px) {
    .MyMixin(10, 1);
  }
}
```

Better solution:

```
.MyMixin(@Count, @ManyOtherVars) {
  width: calc( 100% / @Count);
}

.SomeClass {
  // Lot's of other rules not affected by @Count

  .Item {
    @media screen (max-width: 1000px) {
      .MyMixin(5, 1);
    }
    @media screen (min-width: 1000px) {
      .MyMixin(10, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Now mixin does only one thing. It's simple and reusable.

Comment: The other rules are not static. They depend on the other variables. But the values of those variables don't depend on the media (they may be static in a given context). N.B the requirement that the calling class know nothing about what the mixin does